# Python, run terminal, and execute command in it

Tags: python, linux, os.system

I am using Python 2.7.5, since this version is installed on the machine which I want to run script.

I have created a simple GUI in Tkinter, with button and text input. 
Now in one input I provide the ip, or hostname of server, in next step I read the value of input fields and send it to linux bash terminal, and here I have a problem.

Reading the value from input field(works good)

```
nazwa_ip = self.Input_IP_hostname.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
```

and next:

```
os.system('gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=MY_PROFILE -e "ssh -t user_name@nazwa_ip"')
```

and here is the problem, because it wont change "nazwa_ip" to the read value. That comand send to terminal:

```
ssh -t user_name@nazwa_ip
```

but i want to send:

```
ssh -t user_name@ip_adres_from_input_field
```

Can somebody help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Appreciate your efforts, but why have you added the `bash` tag here, it doesn't look much relevant.

Comment: what about using the subprocess module to execute the command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the Python docs, it is recommended that os.system be replaced with the subprocess module .

```
status = os.system("mycmd" + " myarg")
# becomes
status = subprocess.call("mycmd" + " myarg", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

String formatting will work here:

```
os.system('gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=MY_PROFILE -e "ssh -t user_name@%s"' % nazwa_ip)
```

Comment: Is this a string _comprehension_? Looks like string _formatting_ to me.

Answer (score 0):

Using the subprocess method might be better to do this.

```
import subprocess

nazwa_ip = self.Input_IP_hostname.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
ssh_param = "ssh -t user_name@{}".format(nazwa_ip)
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '--window-with-profile=MY_PROFILE', '-e',  ssh_param])
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst running a subprocess is easy, starting one in a graphical terminal that behaves exactly like one the user launched is a little tricker. You could use my program `interminal` ([link](https://github.com/chrisjbillington/interminal)), which basically does what Stephen Rauch's answer does with `gnome-terminal`, but via a shell so that user environment variables and aliases etc are all available, which could be useful on the offchance that they affect how `ssh` runs.

You would use it from Python like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['interminal', 'ssh', '-t', 'username@{}'.format(ip_address)])
```